# How to add Return Home button to external sites?

Tags: javascript, html, button, frame, hyperlink

I am developing a website with some links to some pages on external websites (belonging to the same company).

The client wants to add a way to easily return to the home site, i.e. something better than just using the browser's Back button, and something better than just opening the external links in a new browser window.

Seeing as I can't control the content of the external pages, I'm guessing that I will have load those external pages into a frame somewhere along the line.

So is there a way for a link to load a local page with a frameset, with the external page loaded into one of the frames? (Then we could have a "Return Home" button in the other frame.)

Or is there a better way to accomplish this? I could stretch to a bit of JavaScript if pushed...

Thanks,

Stewart.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to display the external websites in an iframe, with a link at the top (outside of the iframe) back to your site. Note that some sites employ "iframe busters" which will get rid of your iframe.

The best option is to open in a new tab - it's how people expect the web to work.